# How To Design Scroll View and Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm try to make ScrollView that include ListView(using viewstub) and  Bottom Navigation, I'm try this code below but the image in the scroll view is there in the top, not bottom of the ListView/viewstub, can you help me to fix this problem ? here my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linear1">
            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/stublist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inflatedId="@+id/showlayout"
                android:layout="@layout/list_view"/>
        </LinearLayout>



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/nembelas" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout with sublist and ScrollView have `match_parent` heights (it will cover each other). Also your BottomNavigationView must be placed under the ScrollView to prevent covering of content. You must use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` or `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView` have both set their height to `match_parent` without any constraints. They will both align at the top of their parent.
If you want to show the scrollview below `stublist`, you need to do it like this:

```xml
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stublist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/showlayout"
        android:layout="@layout/list_view"/>
</LinearLayout>



<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
    >
...
```